# how to fetch portfolio array perameters into another page in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

i am facing problem in fetching the portfolio post with type  video perameter in wordpress GT3 theme. the video perameter only shown in the portfolio page. But i want the video perameter on the listing portfolio post page.

listing portfolio post page -- http://www.kemovement.com/
portfolio page -- http://www.kemovement.com/portfolio/i-love-you/

How Can i got the video perameter in the listing page..???

Comment: Can you share what attempts you did solving your issue? The question is not clear, and we expect examples as to what is , and what needs to look like, as in your case it is not clear.

Please add examples, or the specific parameters you need "moved" and which page is exactly which... also: What did you do to solve it?

Comment: Hello Ron, Actually on portfolio i want o play a YouTube video is coming from Post on custom wordpress. there is parameter "Post-format" which was not fetched on portfolio page, i can fetch that parameter on post page. hope you can under stand it.give skype or gmail if you can help me. theme developer is not replying from last 2 days.

Comment: See here .. http://www.kemovement.com/ Video is thumbnail , I want this to directly video not thumbnail.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this code:

```
<?php
// Set up the objects needed
$my_wp_query = new WP_Query();
$all_wp_pages = $my_wp_query->query(array('post_type' => 'page'));
// Get the page as an Object
$portfolio =  get_page_by_title('Portfolio');
// Filter through all pages and find Portfolio's children
$portfolio_children = get_page_children( $portfolio->ID, $all_wp_pages );
// echo what we get back from WP to the browser
echo '<pre>' . print_r( $portfolio_children, true ) . '</pre>';
?>
```

Comment: thanx for your reply jenti. your above code give me the post information in array. but the post format is missing..?

Comment: can u send me your email id or skype id.??

Comment: I had not got Post-format, which shows that it is video or audio or image. which was defined in post, which i want to use on front page show video and show rather than thumbnails.